# Having trouble with TRON 2.0 WAN multiplayer on Proton

Tags: networking, wine, games

So, I'm trying to do WAN multiplayer in TRON 2.0 (Windows-only game released decades ago and is now on Steam), but I can't see any servers (listed on GameSpy), and my friend can't connect to me with my IP even though I have port forwarding set up. I checked my firewall, and the game's port (27888) should be well inside what's allowed. Looking at [this steamcommunity topic](https://steamcommunity.com/app/327740/discussions/0/133261370014213646/) where a Windows user had the same trouble, a mentioned problem source was his antivirus removing two lines from C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts. However, the Proton prefix for TRON 2.0 does not have the "drivers" folder under system32 at all. So, what can I do? Is TRON 2.0 WAN multiplayer impossible on Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was because of two issues:

1. **To allow seeing and joining public servers:** TRON 2.0 originally listed servers on and found servers via the late GameSpy. KillerApp
   Mod restores server listing functionality by adding two lines to the
   Windows hosts file:

   ```
   65.112.87.186 tron20.master.gamespy.com
   65.112.87.186 tron20.ms9.gamespy.com
   ```

   The hosts file acts as sort of a local DNS for the machine, telling
   it how to find the actual DNS but also potentially overriding it.
   These two lines tell TRON 2.0 (and any program really) that the IP
   to GameSpy.com is this custom value, which actually leads to the
   community substitute master server, where TRON 2.0 servers can
   thankfully be listed and found from today. The problem on Linux is
   that wine does not have its own network system, so these attempted
   changes to the nonexistent Windows hosts file are ignored during
   KillerApp Mod installation. However, Linux has its own hosts file, usually at
   /etc/hosts, and thankfully for most distros the syntax in this context is exactly the
   same. **Simply manually add the two GameSpy redirects to the Linux hosts file (usually
   /etc/hosts) to allow TRON 2.0 to find the substitute master server,
   with the list of game servers.**
2. **To allow hosting a server:** TRON 2.0, like most games, uses not only the listed port 27888 but also the +1 port 27889. **Both ports (27888 and 27889) must be configured for port forwarding on the router, and greenlit in the PC firewall, for both TCP and UDP connections, for the PC to be able to host a server.**